# Distinct of date

Tags: sql-server-2000

How to find distinct of date in sql 2000?

For example :i have a table "Dates".It contains different dates like 26-11-2009,
25-11-2009,26-11-2009.'26-11-2009' has two entries.When i select date from this table i need only two entries such as 25-11-2009 and 26-11-2009.

***Edited section:***

In the table 'Emplyoee' there are two fields-JoinDate and EmployeeName.

All Data contains in Emplyoee table is as follows:

```
JoinDate      | EmployeeName
------------------------
02-12-2009   Vijay

03-12-2009   Binoy

03-12-2009   Rahul
```

My select query is as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT JoinDate,EmployeeName FROM Emplyoee
```

I got the Result as follows:

```
JoinDate   | EmployeeName
------------------------
02-12-2009   Vijay
03-12-2009   Binoy
03-12-2009   Rahul
```

But i need the result as follows:

```
JoinDate   | EmployeeName
------------------------
02-12-2009   Vijay
03-12-2009   Binoy(first employee joined on this date)
```

Comment: You need to re-write the question and be more specific, maybe give an example.

Comment: More detail is needed, please provide a specific sample

Comment: Having seen your edit, your title appeared to answer your own question..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT DateAdd(dd, DateDiff(dd, 0, MyDateField),0)
FROM MyTable
```

This will give you the unique dates for your table

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT DISTINCT YourDateTimeField

FROM dbo.YourTable`

although; I'm guessing you want something like this:

`SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(CHAR(10), YourDateTimeField, 101))

FROM dbo.YourTable`

If this is a large table, or if the double conversion would significantly slow things down, you'd want to look for another solution

Answer (score 0):

Having no idea exactly what you require, i can only guess that you need the distinct date values from a filed containg datetime values including times.

So you can try this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT DATEADD(dd,0, DATEDIFF(dd,0,DateVal)) FROM YourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

[Jim B's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1808535/distinct-of-date/1808559#1808559) describes how to get list where every date occurs exactly once.

Or maybe you need dates that occur only once in your table. Your question is unclear.

```
select your_date_field
from your_table
group by your_date_field
having count(1) = 1;
```